# How does condition statement work with bit-wise operators?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I tried to understand how if condition work with bitwise operators.
A way to check if a number is even or odd can be done by:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string test()
{
    int i = 8;  //a number
    if(i & 1)
      return "odd";

    else
      return "even";       
}

int main ()
{
  cout << test();
  return 0;
}
```

The Part I don't understand is how the if condition work. In this case if i = 8 then the in If statement it is doing `1000 & 1` which should gives back 1000 which equal 8.

If i = 7, then in if statement it should be doing `111 & 1` which gives back 111 which equal 7

Why is it the case that if(8) will return "even" and if(7) return "odd"? I guess I want to understand what the if statement is checking to be True and what to be False when dealing with bit-wise operators.

Just A thought when I wrote this question down is it because it's actually doing

```
for 8: 1000 & 0001 which gives 0
for 7: 0111 & 0001 which gives 1?
```

Comment: Your presumptions about what `x & y` return are wrong.

Comment: "what the if statement is checking to be True and what to be False when dealing with bit-wise operators." - condition checking just cares about the final result, never about how it's calculated.

Comment: & is bitwise and. 1000 is 1111101000, while 1 is 1. 1111101000 & 1 is 0, so it's false.

Comment: @Cubic: I assure you, on no system is decimal 8 represented as 1111101000.  On almost all systems, it is 00001000.

Comment: @MooingDuck I get the distinct impression you're trolling. This isn't the first time you replied to a comment of mine in a completely nonsensical way.

Comment: @Cubic Your first comment makes no sense at all. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: @MooingDuck He probably means that the number one thousand (1000 in decimal) is 1111101000 in binary.

Comment: I don't see how the number one thousand is relevant here, since the examples use seven and eight.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you are right in the last part. Binary `&` and `|` are performed bit by bit. Since

```
1 & 1 == 1
1 & 0 == 0
0 & 1 == 0
0 & 0 == 0
```

we can see that:

```
8 & 1 == 1000 & 0001 == 0000
```

and

```
7 & 1 == 0111 & 0001 == 0001
```

Your `test` function does correctly compute whether a number is even or odd though, because `a & 1` tests whether there is a `1` in the 1s place, which there only is for odd numbers.

Comment: nothing more to say here :) Maybe add that 1 & 0 = 0, 1 & 1 = 1 and 0 & 1 = 0

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in C, C++ and other major programming languages the `&` operator do `AND` operations in each bit for integral types. The nth bit in a bitwise `AND` is equal to 1 if and only if the nth bit of both operands are equal to 1.

For example:

```
8 & 1 =
1000 - 8
0001 - 1
----
0000 - 0

7 & 1 =
0111 - 7
0001 - 1
----
0001 - 1

7 & 5 =
0111 - 7
0101 - 5
----
0101 - 5
```

For this reason doing a bitwise `AND` between an even number and `1` will always be equal `0` because only odd numbers have their least significant bit equal to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

What you say the code is doing is actually how bit-wise operators are supposed to work. In your example of (8 & 1):

```
1000 & 0001 = 0000
```

because in the first value, the last bit is set to 0, while in the second value, the last bit is set to 1. 0 & 1 = 0.

```
0111 & 0001 = 0001
```

In both values, the last bit is set to 1, so the result is 1 since 1 & 1 = 1.

Answer (score 3):

`if(x)` in C++ converts `x` to boolean. An integer is considered `true` iff it is nonzero.

Thus, all `if(i & 1)` is doing is checking to see if the least-significant bit is set in `i`. If it is set, `i&1` will be nonzero; if it is not set, `i&1` will be zero.

The least significant bit is set in an integer iff that integer is odd, so thus `i&1` is nonzero iff `i` is odd.

Comment: This is C++ though. `true` is true and `false` is false, just that integers and pointers are still implicitly convertible to `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `i & 1`, where `i` is an `int`, has type `int`. Its value is `1` or `0`, depending on the value of the low bit of `i`. In the statement `if(i & 1)`, the result of that expression is converted to `bool`, following the usual rule for integer types: `0` becomes `false` and non-zero becomes `true`.